# RubyMine - can't find "directory_watcher" gem

Tags: rubygems, rubymine

I am using RubyMine (for the first time) to work on some existing Ruby code, and first thing I see after loading the project is that there is a warning:

[image]

The directory_watcher gem is installed (version 1.4.1) but RubyMine cannot see it.

Is this a known issue, or is there something I need to do to remedy this issue?

Comment: When you say 
"The directory_watcher gem is installed" do you mean at the command line (outside rubyMine) or actually within rubyMine.  Have you  done Tools -> Quick Install gem and looking/selecting it within rubyMine.

Comment: Outside RubyMine ... it was not showing in the list as you described ... so I followed your instructions to install it in RubyMine, so now it shows in the list, but the issue described in my original question still happens.

Comment: Did you bundle install or bundle update to 'get' the gem included in the bundle.

Comment: I just selected "Quick Install Gem" and installed it that way. Prior to that I used "sudo gem install directory_wathcer" on the commandline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define gems in the `Gemfile`, [refer to help](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/ruby-gems-support.html).

Comment: Do I need to have a GemFile for RubyMine to find a gem?

Comment: **Important tip:** RubyMine ignores installed gems (with `gem install`) if they were skipped in `Gemfile`. So, always add gems you are using to `Gemfile`.